# Convert mmm-yy to datetime in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe containing a column having values like feb-20.

How to convert it to datetime

Comment: Use string manipulation to create 01-feb-20 then `pd.to_datetime` with `format='%d-%b-%y'` if that 20 is Year and not day of month.  This is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This will treat the day as 1:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df["col_name"], format="%b-%y")
```

Because you use 2-digit year, there are some oddities around the conversion: anything up to 68 means 20.. while 69+ means 19...